# When to use "also" and when to use "as well"?

Tags: word-usage

The other day it kind of dawned on me that I almost never use "as well" in my talk while native speakers around me do that all the time. I've also noticed that in those cases when the natives say "as well" I would most likely say "also".

Can somebody here give some guidance on when to say "as well" and when to say "also"?

I really don't see any semantic difference between something like:

> "Jenny does that as well."

and

> "Jenny also does that."

The only difference is the placement of the word/phrase in the sentence, but then, again, [the Wikitionary page on the word "also"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/also#Usage_notes) says that:

> "The adverb *also* can go in various places within a sentence, with
> minimal change of meaning:
>
> - The golf courses are excellent. ***Also***, the tennis courts are fantastic.
> - The golf courses are excellent and the tennis courts are fantastic
>   ***also***.
> - Not only are the golf courses excellent but ***also*** the tennis
>   courts are fantastic.
> - There are not just excellent golf courses here.
>   There are ***also*** fantastic tennis courts."

Answer (score 0):

The two mean the same thing. You can use either one without changing the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I don't think it would ever be wrong to use _also_.  "Jenny does that as well" is a shade more informal (and note that _as well_  has to follow the statement it refers to).